# android onactivityresult not getting called

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a normal java class(not an activity ) and I start an intent in the following way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,VerifActivity.class);

              ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        System.out.println("result code is"+resultCode);
        System.out.println("selectedposn is"+selectedPosition);
            }
```

Issue is that the SOPs are not getting printed i.e the onactivity result is not getting called.
The setresult is getting called inthe VerifActivity.class.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a Activity the onActivityResult will not be called. The Activity which you got your context from will be called.

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` is Activity class method not for any JAVA class. Its only works for Android Activity itself.